# During the process of counting ballots in an Election of candidates, Show that $Pr$ ($A$ is ahead during the counting process ) = $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

So this question is apparently from my past papers. I am practicing these for my upcoming exam, but I need a bit of guidance in it. So here is my working I have done so far and the problem I am facing in solving it.

**My Working:**

$1)$ So for the first part of this question I have gone as follows:

The total number of ways of choosing ballot randomly among $a+b$ ballots is: $(a+b)!$

Now if the last ballots to be chosen is from $A$ then there are $a$ possibilities for it and for each $a$ possibilities there are $(a+b-1)!$ possibilities of choosing remaining ballots. Hence:

$Pr$ (the last ballot is vote for $A$) = $\frac{a.(a+b-1)!}{(a+b)!}=\frac{a}{a+b}$

Is my way of arguing and proving part $a$ correct?

Also I am unable to even begin to prove part $b$. I need help in it.Kindly anyone guide and help me. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Look into Catalan numbers and Andre's reflection method. As a matter of fact, the ballot problem is quite famous.

Comment: For part (a), you could have more directly reasoned that the chance that any vote is for $A$ rather than $B$ is the same as the chance that the very first vote is for $A$ rather than $B$.  That is, suppose that when each vote is processed, instead of examining the vote, the vote is sealed in an envelope, and each of the envelopes is given a #, from $1$ through $(a+b)$, inclusive.  Then, when the envelopes are opened for examination, suppose that it is arbitrarily decided that the envelope numbered #1, will be examined last.  Such a decision does not alter the vote that is inside the envelope.

Comment: Re my last comment, see also [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the comment of Ritam Dasgupta, the following related problem is #22 from  "fifty challenging problems in probability" (F. Mosteller).  For the record, no way would I have thought of the following solution on my own.

Assume that $a > b$, and let $P$ denote the chance that at any point in the counting of the votes, there is a tie.  For each sequence of $(2n)$ votes, where the first tie recorded is on the $(2n)$-th vote, if you reverse the balloting of the $(2n)$ votes so that each vote for $a$ becomes a vote for $b$, and vice-versa, then you will have a *mirror-image* sequence of votes that also results in the first tie being recorded on the $(2n)$-th vote.

For each such pair of sequences, exactly one of the two will have the first vote being for $B$, rather than $A$.  Further, for each sequence of votes where the first vote is for $B$, since $a$ is assumed $> b$, such a sequence must result in a tie at some point.

Thus, the chance that the 1st vote is for $B$ is $\frac{b}{a+b}$, and so $P = $the chance that the sequence of votes results in a tie at some point, which equals $2 \times \frac{b}{a+b}.$

Therefore, the chance that $A$ is always ahead is 
$\displaystyle 1 - P = 1 - \frac{2b}{a+b} = \frac{a-b}{a+b}.$

**Edit**
By the way: 
In theory, I am supposed to wait until you show work on part(b), before handing you the answer.  To me, this is similar to asking you to prove Fermat's Last Theorem, and then having Andrew Wiles say that he will have to wait for you to show work before giving you the answer.

If I get downvoted, so be it.  At times, I regard the strict interpretation of the mathSE protocol, as detailed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) as *problematic*, to describe it **generously**.

Comment: The problem gives a hint, and you can quickly get a solution by combining the hint, the solution to part (a), and the typical strategy for induction proofs. Basically, I would not call this FLT level of difficulty.

Comment: I agree that OP showed enough effort to justify the level of detail in your answer; I just resent the implication that genius was required to find the answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Your comment evades the issue that the mathSE protocol, as described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) makes no effort to distinguish between when the OP might routinely have attacked the question, and simply didn't feel like it, versus when the OP might have actually been *lost* with no hope of attacking the question.  In the latter circumstance, I regard the issue of what greater level of sophistication/training is required as irrelevant.  ...see next comment

Comment: @MikeEarnest In the last few months, mathSE reviewers have **policed** hint/answerers who tried to use their judgement at distinguishing the lazy versus the lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to solve the problem using the given hint. Let $E$ be the event that $A$ is always ahead, and let $L_A$ be the event that the last ballot is for $L_A$, similarly for $L_B$. Then as long as $a>b$ (note the strict inequality),
\begin{align}
P(E)
&=P(E|L_A)P(L_A)+P(E|L_B)P(L_B)
\\&=\color{blue}{\frac{(a-1)-b}{(a-1)+b}}\cdot \frac{a}{a+b}+\color{blue}{\frac{a-(b-1)}{a+(b-1)}}\cdot \frac{b}{a+b}
\end{align}
For each of the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ parts, we are applying the induction hypothesis. Given the last ballot is for $A$, the first $a+b-1$ ballots are a mix of $a-1$ ballots for $A$ and $b$ ballots for $B$, and the event that $A$ is ahead during the entire time during these first $a+b-1$ ballots is a smaller version of the original problem. Since we still have $a-1\ge b$, the formula $((a-1)-b)/((a-1)+b)$ applies. The same logic applies to $P(E|L_B)$.

Simplifying that fraction gives the result you want. You also have to deal with the case $a\le b$, but $P(E)$ is obviously $0$ in that case, as desired.